# Xamarin obj\Debug\libraryimports.cache does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new at Xamarin.Android with Visual Studio 2015 and tried to create a little test application.
As soon as I create the new project, a warning appears:

> obj\Debug\libraryimports.cache does not exist. No Imported Libraries found.

If I try to start the application, VS tells me, that there is a problem and asks me to go further.
I tried to reinstall Xamarin and Visual Studio and tried to create the Project on my Desktop.
In every case it shows me the same Warning.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to move the whole Visual Studio solution to a path with only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

Move the solution to c:\new_folder\solution. *new_folder* and *solution* **must** contains **only ASCII characters**. My username in windows has "í".

This solution work for me.

Comment: Still the same problem on VS 2015. Moving the solution to a new path with ASCII characters solve the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like reinstalling is the only known solution: [Rebuild failed: ''obj\Debug\libraryimports.cache does not exist. No Imported Libraries found''](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61623/rebuild-failed-obj-debug-libraryimports-cache-does-not-exist-no-imported-libraries-found)